# How to skip controller name while using RedirectToAction?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, redirecttoaction

I have accountController class and its have login & home views.

```
    [HandleError]
    public class accountController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult login(LoginModal model, string returnUrl)
        {
             //Authentication
             return RedirectToAction("home"); 
        }
        public ActionResult home()
        {
             return View(); 
        }
    } 
------------------------------
-----------------------------
Global.asax have Route entry.. so my urls is 
http://lmenaria.com/login
http://lmenaria.com/home

routes.MapRoute(null, "home", new { controller = "account", action = "home" });
routes.MapRoute(null, "login", new { controller = "account", action = "login" });
```

When I tried the both URL on browser they are working fine. But when login success then its go to http://lmenaria.com/account/home
So how can I remove "account" from this url. this is going when I used return RedirectToAction("home"); and getting 404 error.

So please let me know how can I resolved that issue. I don't need Controller Name in url.

Thanks
Laxmilal Menaria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

routes.MapRoute("home", "home", new { controller = "account", action = "home" });

I tried with Above MapRoute & use RedirectToRoute instead of RedirectTOAction and its work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to default the controller to "account", without showing it in your URL, then you can do something like

routes.MapRoute(null, "{action}", new { controller = "account" });

if you want, you can use a default value for action too

routes.MapRoute(null, "{action}", new { controller = "account", action = "home" });

---

I'm editing my answer to let you know that you don't need to explicitly define each route as you're doing. MVC routes match patterns. So, instead of

`routes.MapRoute(null, "home", new { controller = "account", action = "home" });`
`routes.MapRoute(null, "login", new { controller = "account", action = "login" });`

use just

`routes.MapRoute(null, "{action}", new { controller = "account" });`

And pay attention to the routes order if you define more than one pattern, because order matters. MVC will use the first pattern that matches your URL.

Answer (score 0):

I think the real issue is that you either didn't create or removed the home controller.

From your description it really sounds like you should be calling RedirectToAction for the Home controller Index action.

Answer (score 0):

you have [HttpPost] on your Login action. Which should be the problem. I just run your codes without [HttpPost] attribute. it is working. when you type http://lmenaria.com/login, your "login" action will not be fired, because of the attribute. so, there must be some other routes that does the routing.